# Error "Metric (TFM) file not found" with MacTex 2016

Tags: install, macos, latex

I want to use TexMaker as LaTeX editor on a Macbook with OS X 10.9.5.

I installed TexMaker 4.5 and MacTex 2016.

A first attempt to compile a given document (that was written with TexMaker on a Linux computer) gives errors because some `.sty` files are missing. So I looked for them on the internet and put them in the folder that contains my document.

A second attempt to compile the document gives following error:

> Error ! Font U/psy/m/n/10=psyr at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

I read on tex.SE [still searching the post] that this can be due to multiple LaTeX distributions being installed on your computer. I think that this can be the case. How can I check which versions are installed? Or could there be a different cause?

**Update**

In `usr/local/texlive` there was a folder `2016` and `2016basic`. I removed the `2016` folder but the problem persists.

**Update 2**
According to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found):

> On macOS / MacTeX `install collection-fontsrecommended` in the TeX Live Utility or `tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended` from the command line.

I did the latter from the command line. It said

> tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
>
> ===============================================================================
>
> tlmgr itself needs to be updated.
>
> Please do this via either
>
> tlmgr update --self
>
> or by getting the latest updater for Unix-ish systems:
>
> http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
>
> and/or Windows systems:
>
> http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe
>
> Then continue with other updates as usual.
>
> ===============================================================================
>
> tlmgr: Terminating; please see warning above!

So I proceeded with `tlmgr update --self` and it said

> tlmgr: package repository
>
> http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
>
> tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2016basic/tlpkg/backups
> /Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: create(tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.tlpobj) failed: Permission denied at /usr/local/texlive/2016basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 561.

How to proceed?

Comment: The problem seemed to be caused by multiple versions of MacTex being installed. I removed them all and reinstalled one version.

Comment: This question will probably be deleted.